# ADF - Pipeline Expression Builder - Error using convertTimeZone()

Tags: azure-data-factory

I get the error attached when using the convertTimeZone() function in the pipeline expression builder. Any help here, please?[image: Error]

See below for the - Actual Base URL in which I'm trying to include convertTimeZone(). The reason to change from addHours() to convertTimeZone() is to avoid manual intervention in changing UTC+1 / UTC+0 during day light savings in London.

NOTE: This is only in the case of Linked services expression builder.

This works -
[image: Works]

This doesn't work -
[image: Doesn't work]

Answer (score 0):

> This is only in the case of Linked services expression builder.

Since this is the case, you can simply pass the value from your pipeline. You can do it as shown below:

- Create a parameter in REST dataset and REST linked service as `url_from_dataset` and `url_from_ls` respectively.
- You can pass the required url built with the help of dynamic content from your pipeline source to dataset. And from dataset, you can pass it to Linked service.
- Parameter created in linked service (RestService1) and dynamic content given in `Base URL` as:

```
@linkedService().url_from_ls
```

[image]

- Parameter created in dataset (`url_from_dataset`) and value is passed to linked service parameter as:

```
@dataset().url_from_dataset
```

[image]

- Now in your pipeline source, say copy data for example, **pass the URL created use convertTimeZone() as a value to `url_from_dataset`. The following image is a reference:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it works, I tried to save the linked service without testing the connection and when I used this linked service in my pipeline source it gave the same error.

Comment: Same error as in `HttpInvalidUrlAddress` or the original error as in the question?

Comment: Original Error as in the question.

Comment: Can you please confirm this, you are using `convertTimeZone()` to provide a `URL` while creating linked service. It creates current time in specified time zone which is not a URL. Is it the URL you want to connect to?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the actual base URL. Check for more details